# How to update a domain object with ViewModel and AutoMapper using Entity framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

How do i update a domain object with ViewModel with AutoMapper using Entity framework?

I have a View to edit a Question entity.

This is my Edit action:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    var question = db.Question.Single(q => q.question_id == id);

    Mapper.CreateMap<Question, EditQuestionViewModel>();
    EditQuestionViewModel eqvm = Mapper.Map<Question, EditQuestionViewModel>(question);

    eqvm.QuestionTypes = new SelectList(db.Question_Type, "type_code", "type_description", question.type_code);
    eqvm.Categories = new SelectList(db.Category, "category_id", "category_name", question.category_id);

    eqvm.Visibility = new SelectList(new Dictionary<int, string> {
        { 1, "Ja"},
        { 0, "Nej"}
    }, "Key", "Value");

    return View(eqvm);
}
```

And my ViewModel looks like this:

```
 public class EditQuestionViewModel
{
    public int question_id { get; set; }
    public string question_wording { get; set; }
    public bool visible { get; set; }
    public int question_number { get; set; }
    public string help_text { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; }
    public Question_Type Question_Type { get; set; }

    public string SelectedCategory { get; set; }
    public string SelectedQuestionType { get; set; }
    public SelectList Categories { get; set; }
    public SelectList QuestionTypes { get; set; }
    public SelectList Visibility { get; set; }
    public string RefUrl { get; set; }

}
```

This is the View:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "AdminQuestion", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Spørgsmål</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.question_wording, "Spørgsmål")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.question_wording, new { @class = "required", rows = 3, cols = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.question_wording)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, "Hvilken kategori tilhører dette spørgsmål?")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedCategory, Model.Categories)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedCategory)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(x => x.SelectedQuestionType, "Spørgsmålstype")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedQuestionType, Model.QuestionTypes)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SelectedQuestionType)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.visible, "Skal dette spørgsmål være synligt?")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.visible, Model.Visibility)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.visible)
        </div>

          <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.question_number, "Hvilket nummer har spørgsmålet inden for sin kategori?")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.question_number, new { @class = "required digits" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.question_number)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.help_text, "Hjælpetekst som hjælper brugeren med at forstå spørgsmålet:")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.help_text, new { rows = 20, cols = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.help_text)
        </div>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Gem" />

    </fieldset>
```

How do i update the entity when i submit the form ?
How should the mapping between the ViewModel and EF Model look like, using AutoMapper?

The properties

```
public string SelectedCategory { get; set; }
public string SelectedQuestionType { get; set; }
```

In the ViewModel are supposed to be linked with category_id and type_code in the EF model

Also notice the property

```
public bool visible { get; set; }
```

I use BIT in my database. Will this work with the values 0 and 1, which is use in the SelectList?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you would need to get the object from entity framework, and then use automapper like this:

```
var item = repository.getbyid(model.Id);
_mappingEngine.Map(viewModel, item);
repository.save(item);
```

Comment: Thanks! :) I found out that i have to use repository.SaveChanges(); with the EF. Also, i have to do _mapEngine.CreateMap<EditQuestionViewModel, Question>() before i can use _mappEnginge.Map(); - If you can edit your answer to be more precise i can mark it as answered!

Comment: repository implementations are all different, so the actual kind of repository should not really factor in.  the point was how you should get an entity reference, you can't just new up an entity from your mapper.  the createmap call shouldn't actually happen in the code where you need it, but in an automapper profile that you spin up in your global.asax using a bootstrapper or more direct means.  seems like your question should not have had anything to do with entity framework, just how can i use automapper.

Comment: This is the correct approach. However, it appears that Automapper has a problem dealing with EF proxies, so beware of this if you are using POCOs with lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form, you need to have an action on your controller that will handle the post to the server.

So in addition to the Edit action you currently have, you will need to have another action defined like so:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EditQuestionViewModel model)
{
    //Do the mapping to from your ViewModel to the EF model here

    return View();
}
```

What this does is sets up a handler so your form can post the data back to the controller and it will bind your fields on your form to the model parameter.

Once you have done this, you can simply map the model back to EF and persist it to the database.

Also, using a bool is perfectly valid and EF will translate and save it as a 0 or 1 in the database for you.

Comment: Sorry i was not clear enough in my question. How should the mapping from my ViewModel to the EF Model look like? Assuming i use AutoMapper

Comment: Using AutoMapper to map from your VM back to your DM is dangerous because it may try and set more values than you want it to, which could cause unexpected results.

Comment: @lomaxx, automapper will only map what you tell it to.  if you use the basic CreateMap<>() without telling it how to map it will try to match field names.  you should almost always define exactly how the map should work.

Comment: @nathan: This is true, but it will always try and map those properties, so if you just need to be careful how you use it.

Comment: @lomaxx, that's what profiles are for.  if you want to map the same object differently in different contexts, inject a mapping engine with a different set of profiles.

Comment: @nathan - correct, but that isn't the default way most people use it and since all profiles loaded into the "global" mapping space by default you just need to be careful... hence the reason I said it's dangerous

Comment: @lomaxx,  i guess my point is saying its dangerous to use automapper because it has default behavior is like saying its dangerous to program.  of course its dangerous to use something the wrong way.